# Swift TableView multiple Custom cells, inrease number of row in from cell lead to crash

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have problem which trying to solve for hours.

I have tableView with multiple cells. 
I don't use StoryBoard.

My problem is this: 
Number of cells in tableView depends on size of array. When app start, tableView and its cells loads perfectly. Even when i insert into ViewDidLoad this:

```
arrayOfCategory.append(Category(nameOfCategory: "Example", ColorOfCategory: .white))
tableView.reloadData()
```

it works. But when i try insert voids into button's target

```
@objc func handle(sender: UIButton)  {
    arrayOfCategory.append(Category(nameOfCategory: "Sdsdd", ColorOfCategory: .white))
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

my app will crash with error:

```
TaskList[59513:1886772] Could not cast value of type 'TaskList.SwitchCell' (0x1073bd808) to 'TaskList.CategoryShowCell' (0x1073bd500).
```

Here is cellForRow:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        tableView.register(CategoryShowCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: categoryShowID)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: categoryShowID, for: indexPath) as! CategoryShowCell
          cell.setCell(category: Category(nameOfCategory: "sdsd", ColorOfCategory: .white))
        return cell

    case 1:
        tableView.register(SwitchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: swichCellID)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: swichCellID, for: indexPath) as! SwitchCell
        return cell
    default:
        tableView.register(SwitchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: swichCellID)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: swichCellID, for: indexPath) as! SwitchCell

        return cell
    }

}
```

Does anyone know where is problem?
Xcode point into this line:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: categoryShowID, for: indexPath) as! CategoryShowCell
```

in cellForRow bude one line above i register right cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in different types of registered cell and type you're trying to force cast it to. Like Xcode says you - `TaskList.SwitchCell` to `TaskList.CategoryShowCell`. Force casting happens at `as! CategoryShowCell` this place.

I suspect, that you are reregistering `SwitchCell.self` for `categoryShowID`. It can happen if your `categoryShowID` is equal to `swichCellID`.

Check this out and keep in mind, that registering one cell multiple times in `cellForRow` is a bad idea

Comment: I am embarassed, I typed anwer when i noticed categoryShowID and switchCellID is the same string. I moved tableview.register ... to viewDidLoad and everything work. Thank you very much and sorry i wasted your time.

Comment: @Angelus, it's totally fine